# making plugin for auto commiting any file change in github

Tags: php, wordpress, github, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I am making plugin in wordpress site, which see if any changes in any file occured, if they did, then committing the whole codebase to github. I know how to use github api in php, but I need to know, how will I look at changes happening in the wordpress site. Is there wp hook or php code to do it.

I tried to look at the current theme's directory and scanning all the files with scan($files) function, and check for file modifcations with wp_check_file_modifications($files) plugin function, but it works for core wordpress files.

```
<!-- to get the current theme's directory -->
$theme_directory = get_template_directory();
<!-- to scan through all the files in current directory -->
$files = scandir($theme_directory);
echo 'All files in current theme Directory:' . "\n";
print_r($files);

if ( wp_check_file_modifications( $files ) ) {
    At least one of the files has been modified
  } else {
    All of the files have not been modified
}
```

Is there any other way around it or any other idea with which I can approach this problem? Thanks in advance for help.